# graylog - server wont connect to port 9000

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog

I am trying to set up a graylog-server  by their [docs](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.0/pages/faq.html)

I installed everything , turned on elastic search , installed mongo , configurated files , added name / passwd hashed and yet when i visit localhost:9000 is still unable to connect.

I tried to start up everything again

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
sudo service mongodb start
sudo service graylog-server start
sudo service rsyslog start
sudo service apache2 start
```

but it didnt work

Has anyone met with similliar problem? I am trying to make it work for few hours but nothing works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make port 12900 available, because this is the port of the REST API which the web interface uses to connect to. You can find more information about this [here](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.0/pages/configuration/web_interface.html).